# Not able to access localhost on android device on the same network

Tags: android, ubuntu, localhost, apache2

I have installed apache2 on ubuntu and then using it to setup localhost which although can be accessed on the same computer but not on the android on the same network. I remember i could do this previously but now it isn't happening. I want to send files to my android through localhost quickly. Any solution?

Comment: `localhost` refers to the physical device you type `localhost` on, to your phone, localhost it the phone, you your desktop, localhost is the desktop. To connect to your desktop from your phone, you will need to enter in IP address of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is usually just an alias for the loopback address `127.0.0.1`, which means "this computer".  So, On your android phone, you are telling it to send this files to "this computer", which is the phone itself.  You need the IP address of your local computer, which usually can be found by running `ifconfig` from the command line.  Depending on your network setup, the output of this will have a bunch of stuff, and you should look through the output for anything that resembles an IP address, usually this is under the `en0` or `eth0` sections (I'm not a networking expert).

Answer (score 0):

To access the Local server  from device you should set the URL IN YOUR code to the local ip instead of 127.0.0.1
    CMD>ipconfig> (IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.XXX )

then Connect to the same Network and all fine or you can download [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) 
as its support Linux OS and will Automatically install needed tools like

> Apache2 , Mysql and support MariaDB + PHP + Perl

you can find useful answears in this Thread
[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device?rq=1)

as its answered before